# Download Content-Disposition from ASP.NET CORE api in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

How to download foo.txt in angular I have a asp.net core backend where I return a foo.txt file.
string file is not being used for now.

Here is my backend

```
// GET api/download/contractAttachment
[HttpGet("download/{file}")]
public IActionResult GetFileAsync(string file)
{
    return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("foo"), "text/plain", "foo.txt");
}
```

Here is my angular front-end

```
  download(file: string) {

    this.contractAttachementsService.downloadFile().subscribe(blob => {
        //I am not entering here how can I downloadFile here
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
```

As you can see in postman I can see the file but how can I download it in angular. Thank you for your help

[image: Headers]

Answer (score 0):

since I see a blob in the subscription right there in the Angular snippet here is what you can do:

```
 download(file: string) {
    this.contractAttachementsService.downloadFile().subscribe((res)=> {
    // response to blob
    const blob = new Blob([res], {
    // Define the blob coversion type such as an xl file in my case
      type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    // in the case of a text file you can probably use built-in method
    // blob.text():
    // read here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text
    })
    // Sanitizing the DOM against  XSS attacks (Cross Sit Scripting injections) and assign the sanitized object url to the fileUrl property
    this.fileToBeDownloaded = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      // create a an object url from the response sanitized blob
      window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    )

    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
```

You need to declare a property that will hold the file to be downloaded and also inject the `DOMSanitizer` from `'@angular/platform-browser'`

Then,
In your template you should have an action to download the file. You can use property binding that is bound to the `fileTobDownloaded`  property there in the `ts` part as follows:

```html
 <a [href]="fileToBeDownloaded"  download="fileName.txt">Download</a>
```

Hope this helps you in your project